# Creating a new elastic search client with every requests

Tags: php, laravel, performance, elasticsearch

I was checking a part of my application in which I connect to elasticsearch host server and then I realized for every time the front-end sends an report request to my back-end I'm creating an instance of elasticsearch client class using the following code :

```php
$elasticClient = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($this->setHostsParams())->build();
```

Since our application sends about 20 requests to the back-end by loading the first page, I was considering if PHP's elasticsearch library might be capable of optimizing the initiation phase, or if anyone has a better solution for this, or it might not be a big of a deal after all and it's not a real overhead!?

PS : I did some research with it and didn't find any resources covering this subject.

Comment: You could either use connection pool (take a look to swoole) or send everything in 1 request instead of 20.

Comment: on my side I always use it in a singleton to avoid recreating a separate connection each time I need the client.

Comment: Keep it in mind that in PHP a singleton will be created with a new request and destructed as soon as the request is served, what I'm dealing with is different forms of elasticsearch aggregations in different API endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing an object instance is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908108/8160318) and elsewhere so I'm not going to go into that.

What I'd point out, though, is there there's an elasticsearch API called `_msearch` which enables you to send multiple search payloads at the same time and the system will respond after all the individual requests have resolved. Here's some [sample PHP usage](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-0-php-msearch/66716/2).

This might be useful if you need all your ~20 requests resolved at once -- though it may be useless if you defer some of those requests only after, say, a user scrolls down and what not.